# How to add a ipv6 range on ubuntu and use it as a proxy server

Tags: proxy, ip, ipv6

i have a ipv6 range (/64) i got from hurricane electric internet services.
It has exactly
18,446,744,073,709,551,616
ipv6 addresses in the range.

so what im planning to do is , use each of the ip address as a proxy .
is it possible ? if yes , how can i do that ?

in short i want to make a pool of ipv6 proxies
using that range

Comment: Why? The point of IPv6 is that each host gets its own public address, restoring the IP paradigm. Normally, you would get that network as a transit network, then get a `/48` prefix from HE, giving you 65,536 `/64` networks.

Comment: so dosent that mean every ip on a ipv6 range can act as a proxy server ? since there are almost infinite amount of ipv6 addresses.

Comment: Why do you need a proxy? If it is for the web, the simply configure your proxy server (it only needs a single address) and the PAC file for the browsers. If you are wanting a more general proxy, the you configure something else like WAAS on your router or set the gateway as the proxy server. In any case, the source and destination addresses on the IPv6 packets remain the same through the entire path (no NAT), restoring the IP end-to-end paradigm, which is the point of IPv6.

Comment: i want to install a proxy on each of the ipv6 address in order to avoid data scraping restrictions .

Comment: You can assign multiple IPv6 addresses to an interface, but certainly not that many. Remember, the network stack for that interface will need to record any addresses assigned to it, and that takes RAM. It is normally a very small amount, but it needs 128 bits (16 bytes) per address. Just to keep track of each of the addresses would require 16 times 18,446,744,073,709,551,616 bytes of RAM, which is far more than any PC ever had. It is 16 times the theoretical maximum of a 64-bit CPU.

Comment: so how many can i make on a 16 gb ram server and how ?

Comment: That is up to your OS and its resources. You need to ask a question like this on the proper SE site. It is a server configuration question, not a programming question.